# Loop get_theme_mod

Tags: loop, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I've got a bunch of customizer settings set up

Rather than calling individual get_theme_mod statements for each setting individually, is there a way to simplify it to loop thru them without having to explicitly write each one individually?

The complete file is also setup on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/00a9567352d1905283e6) for review

```
<?php


/** Adds the Customize page to the WordPress admin area */
function litho_customizer_menu() {
    add_theme_page( 'Customize', 'Customize', 'edit_theme_options', 'customize.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'litho_customizer_menu' );

/** Adds the individual sections, settings, and controls to the theme customizer */
function litho_customizer( $wp_customize ) {
    class Example_Customize_Textarea_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
        public $type = 'textarea';

        public function render_content() { ?>
            <label>
                <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
                <textarea rows="5" style="width:100%;" <?php $this->link(); ?>><?php echo esc_textarea( $this->value() ); ?></textarea>
            </label>
        <?php }
    }

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'site_settings', array(
            'title' => 'Framework Settings',
            'description' => 'Adjust settings',
            'priority' => 35,
    ));


/* <?php echo $sidebar_position; ?> */



    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'site-subtitle', array( 'default' => 'Default subtitle text','sanitize_callback' => 'litho_sanitize_text', ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control('site-subtitle', array(
            'label' => 'Copyright text',
            'section' => 'site_settings',
            'type' => 'text'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'litho_copyright_textbox',array( 'default' => 'Default copyright text','sanitize_callback' => 'litho_sanitize_text', ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'litho_copyright_textbox',array(
            'label' => 'Copyright text',
            'section' => 'site_settings',
            'type' => 'text'
    ));

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'litho_hide_copyright',array('sanitize_callback' => 'litho_sanitize_checkbox',) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'litho_hide_copyright',array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'label' => 'Hide copyright text',
                'section' => 'site_settings'
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'litho_logo_placement', array( 'default' => 'left','sanitize_callback' => 'litho_sanitize_logo_placement', ) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'litho_logo_placement',array(
                'type' => 'radio',
                'label' => 'Logo placement',
                'section' => 'site_settings',
                'choices' => array( 'left' => 'Left','right' => 'Right','center' => 'Center')
        ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'litho_powered_by', array( 'default' => 'wordpress','sanitize_callback' => 'litho_sanitize_powered_by', ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'litho_powered_by',array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => 'This site is powered by:',
            'section' => 'site_settings',
            'choices' => array( 'wordpress' => 'WordPress','nuclear-energy' => 'Nuclear Energy')
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'page-setting', array( 'sanitize_callback' => 'litho_sanitize_integer', ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'page-setting',array(
            'type' => 'dropdown-pages',
            'label' => 'Choose a page:',
            'section' => 'site_settings'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'color-setting', array( 'default' => '#000000','sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color', ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'color-setting',array(
            'label' => 'Color Setting',
            'section' => 'site_settings',
            'settings' => 'color-setting'
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'file-upload' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( $wp_customize, 'file-upload',array(
            'label' => 'File Upload',
            'section' => 'site_settings',
            'settings' => 'file-upload'
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'img-upload' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'img-upload',array(
            'label' => 'Image Upload',
            'section' => 'site_settings',
            'settings' => 'img-upload'
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'textarea' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new Example_Customize_Textarea_Control( $wp_customize, 'textarea',array(
            'label' => 'Textarea',
            'section' => 'site_settings',
            'settings' => 'textarea'
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'font-color', array( 'default' => '#444444', 'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color', ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'font-color',array(
            'label' => 'Font Color',
            'section' => 'colors',
            'settings' => 'font-color'
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'featured-background',array( 'default' => '#ffffff','sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color','transport' => 'postMessage', ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize,'featured-background',array(
            'label' => 'Featured Background',
            'section' => 'colors',
            'settings' => 'featured-background'
    )));

    /* AJAX function for live preview */
    if ( $wp_customize->is_preview() && ! is_admin() ) {
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'litho_customize_preview', 21);
    }

    function litho_customize_preview() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'litho-customize-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/core/js/customize.js',array());
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'litho_customize_preview' );

    $wp_customize->get_setting('blogname')->transport='postMessage';
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'litho_customizer' );

function litho_header_alignment() {
    $litho_position = get_theme_mod( 'litho_logo_placement' );
    if( $litho_position != '' ) {
        switch ( $litho_position ) {
            case 'left':
                break;
            case 'right':
                echo '<style type="text/css">';
                echo '#header #logo{ float: right; }';
                echo '</style>';
                break;
            case 'center':
                echo '<style type="text/css">';
                echo '#header{ text-align: center; }';
                echo '#header #logo{ float: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }';
                echo '</style>';
                break;
        }
    }
}
add_action ( 'wp_head','litho_header_alignment' );

/* The force_balance_tags() function ensures that no tags are left unclosed, while the wp_kses_post() ensures that only safe tags make it into the database (the same tags that are allowed in a standard WordPress post */
function litho_sanitize_text( $input ) {
    return wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags( $input ) );
}
function litho_sanitize_checkbox( $input ) {
    if ( $input == 1 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
function litho_sanitize_logo_placement( $input ) {
    $valid = array(
        'left' => 'Left',
        'right' => 'Right',
        'center' => 'Center',
    );

    if ( array_key_exists( $input, $valid ) ) {
        return $input;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function litho_sanitize_powered_by( $input ) {
    $valid = array(
        'wordpress' => 'WordPress',
        'nuclear-energy' => 'Nuclear Energy',
    );

    if ( array_key_exists( $input, $valid ) ) {
        return $input;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
function litho_sanitize_integer( $input ) {
    if( is_numeric( $input ) ) {
        return intval( $input );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `get_them_mods()` which will...

> > Retrieve all theme modification values for the current theme.
> >
> > If no theme mods have been set, will return boolean false.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mods

It should return an `array` that you can loop over.

Comment: Can you provide an example or does the example on the codex pretty much work straight outa the box?  I'm just pretty new at WP.  Thx

Comment: `get_theme_mods()` is pretty straightforward. I can post an example if you have trouble.

Comment: As of now, `get_theme_mods()` does not work with customizer. Customizer uses the filter of `get_theme_mod()` to change the values, temporarily. There's no such filter in `get_theme_mods()`